# Pagination next previous multiplied

Tags: php

Please forgive me if i make some mistake in english its not my native language.
To the point. This is my pagination code:

```
if (!isset($_GET["page"])) $_GET["page"] = 1;
if (sizeof($dirs) + sizeof($files) > $thumbs_pr_page)
{
    $page_navigation .= "$label_page ";
    for ($i=1; $i <= ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page); $i++)
    {
        if ($_GET["page"] == $i)
            $page_navigation .= "$i";
            else
                $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
                $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i-1) . "'> Previous </a>";
                $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i+1) . "'> Next </a>";
        if ($i != ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page)) $page_navigation .= " | ";


    }   
}
```

Any ideas where is the problem ? The next/ previous button is mutliplied. But it should be only on the left side should be previous and on the right side next. I am only learning php now and its hard for me. Here you can see it how it looks: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2djl3m&s=5 and it should be like this: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eeli54&s=5

Comment: What do you mean by it's multiplied? Can you please [edit] into your question what **you are getting** and what **you are expecting to get**?

Comment: Here you can see it how it looks: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2djl3m&s=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the next and previous button out of your for-loop. Previous at front, next after it. Next and Previous dont need to depend on $i - they should depend on the currently loaded page, only.

```
if (!isset($_GET["page"])) $_GET["page"] = 1;
if (sizeof($dirs) + sizeof($files) > $thumbs_pr_page)
{
    $page_navigation .= "$label_page ";

    $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($_GET["page"]-1) . "'> Previous </a>";

    for ($i=1; $i <= ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page); $i++)
    {
        if ($_GET["page"] == $i)
            $page_navigation .= "$i";
        else
            $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
        if ($i != ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page)) $page_navigation .= " | ";


    }   
    $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($_GET["page"]+1) . "'> Next </a>";
}
```

But you should also "catch" `0` and `n+1` pages (then no Previous / Next Button is required)

Comment: @user2466042 Add `if ($_GET["page"]> 1) { }` around the previous link, and `if ($_GET["page"] < ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page) { }` around the next link.

Comment: dognose your second answer is good but missing two parenthesis () it should be if ($_GET["page"]< (ceil((sizeof($files) + sizeof($dirs)) / $thumbs_pr_page))) { } But thank you for your professional reply ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your for loop. You are checking if `$_GET['page'] == $i` and if not you are concatenating links to `$page_navigation`

```
$page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
$page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i-1) . "'> Previous </a>";
$page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i+1) . "'> Next </a>";
```

This will generate Next / Previous link for each iteration where `$_GET['page'] == $i` is not true (which is always except once). Since you need them only once (relative to current `$_GET['page']`) you need to move them outside the loop.

Comment: I solved it now i have it good now in the right position. Thank you. But the previous next buttons are not working correctly. It leaves blank when i click on them it doenst go to next page or previous.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please try and put brackets in the after the `else`, because, the last two statements in the `else` will not be a part of the `else` clause, which will cause the Previous and Next to be a part of the `for(;;;)` instead of the `else`, and that is causing it to maybe repeat the Previous and Next.

```
        if ($_GET["page"] == $i)
            $page_navigation .= "$i";
        else{
            $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
            $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i-1) . "'> Previous </a>";
            $page_navigation .= "<a href='?dir=" . $_GET["dir"] . "&amp;page=" . ($i+1) . "'> Next </a>";
         }
```